# Mongoose - Independent Unique Constraints

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, unique

I am trying to get two independent unique constraints on one Schema to work but...

```
var Game = new Schema({
    name: String,
    shortName: String
})
Game.index({ name: 1, shortName: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

... always creates a compound index which makes the following table valid:

```
name: "Foo", shortName: "Bar";
name: "Foo", shortName: "Foo";
```

Is there any way to make those unique contraints independent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [**unique index documentation**](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) :

> You can also enforce a unique constraint on compound indexes. These
>   indexes enforce uniqueness for the **combination** of index keys and **not**
>   for either key individually.

so to achieve this you'll need to create a unique index on each field, like this:

```js
var Game = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, unique: true }, 
    shortName: { type: String, unique: true }
  }
)
```

Comment: `var Game = new Schema({ name: { type: String, unique: true }, shortName: { type: String, unique: true } })` Like this?

Comment: @Pat yes exactly